# Unable to remove file or change permission on mac as root.

Tags: macos

I cant remove files from /Library/Extensions/ even if i run bash script as root.

- I also tried to change flags with

  `chflags -R nouchg
  chflags -R noschg`
- Here is output for `ls -l` even after `chmod -R 777`:

  `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  96 Aug  7 12:25 FileProtect.kext`
- `rm -rf` returns following:

  `rm: /Library/Extensions/FileProtect.kext: Permission denied`

What can be reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a 2 reasons I can think of why this file (well, directory) might not be deletable.

1. Check for the "restricted" flag. This is part of SIP, and you should be able to see it via `ls -lO /Library/Extensions/FileProtect.kext`. If following the group you see "restricted" then this file is flagged as being protected via SIP. This shouldn't normally be the case for a file under /Library/ but people do the weirdest things.
2. The kext itself is blocking the delete operation. As it's in /Library/Extensions, there's a reasonable chance it's loaded automatically. If it implements a kauth vnode scope listener or a MAC policy, it can arbitrarily deny file operations, including deletions.

In either case, the solution is to boot into the recovery environment and to delete it there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed a way to do it without rebooting. It seems like the task is impossible. In my particular case there is a way actually. `FileProtect.kext` is a part of Bitdefender Antivirus. Bitdefender is distributed with self uninstall script. I broke it and execution did not delete Antivirus, but it turned off self protection. Without it I eventually got managed to remove Bitdefender.